# Monitoring servers using Dell OpenManage or IPMI

Tags: monitoring, dell, ipmi, dell-openmanage

We have some Dell servers, 11th and 12th generation.
These servers supports IPMI over LAN and Dell OpenManage.

As I can see, I looks like I can get all the sensor data, from both OpenManage and IPMI.

Can anybody tell me the difference between then? What should be used for monitoring hardware health?

Answer (score 1):

They should be the same information. And if they arn't then that's a bug with one (or both) of the implementations.

What should you use? Whatever you monitoring system supports. If you have OpenManage installed, it will also expose that information via SNMP.

Comment: Thanks. The monitoring system supports both SNMP and IPMI, so I can use both.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely go with IPMI as it's an industry standard.
You may currently only have Dell systems monitored by your infrastructure, but what in a few years?
At our largish site (1500+ systems, 1000+ of which are Dell) we definitely work with IPMI. It's even a requirement in our requests for tender.
Moreover, many different monitoring solutions, including opensource, support this protocol.
I couldn't recomment a closed product.

Answer (score -1):

another dell tool you can use is OMPC. It's the power and thermal side of the OpenMange Dell SW line